# How to prompt a user to share a photo to FB using Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a function that is called on a click.  I want to have a dialog box open that allows a user to publish an image to their FB wall.  I am using the Javascript SDK.  When this runs, however, nothing happens.  Any ideas?:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({ appId: '***********', cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true });
        // *** here is my code ***
        if (typeof facebookInit == 'function') {
            facebookInit();
        }
    };

    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));

/* make the API call */
function facebookInit() {
    FB.api(
        "/me/photos",
        "POST",
        {
            "object": {
                "url": "https://graph.facebook.com/*******/picture?width=720&height=720"
            }
        },
        function (response) {
            if (response && !response.error) {
                window.location = "http://url.com";
            }
        }
     );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are publishing photo using the **Graph API**, not the dialog.

In fact you cannot post a photo using a dialog, that's the correct way of doing which you are following.

Another thing, instead of-

```
"object": {
   "url": "https://graph.facebook.com/*******/picture?width=720&height=720"
}
```

simply send the `url` parameter. The `object` jey is not required.

And you can always check the response/error in `console.log(response)`

Comment: There is no error coming up in the console.  But nothing is happening.

Comment: You mean there's nothing in `console.log(response)`? Well this can never happe. Pl check your code properly

Comment: Ok, I understand I can't do this by dialog, but is there a way that I can prompt a user to share the photo?  As opposed to just sharing it automatically.

Comment: Just to share a photo- No you can't. But of course you can implement this by yourself using the graph api.

Comment: I got this error: code: 2500
message: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
type: "OAuthException"

Comment: At what point are you getting this? This message occurs wherever you try to access `/me/feed` without logging in. Btw this isnt related to this ques, pl check the code and if you find problem post as another ques. If your current question is solved pls mark it correct

Comment: It is not.  I have a logged in user at this stage.  How do I point that user to this?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not able to understand what are you trying to say. And you should ask this as a seperate ques explaining with your code